# Add multiple MYSQLI results as an array value in a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this script that converts mysqli records into an array and i'm using a foreach loop to show those results. The problem I have is how can I show the gender value of the array_column as well in the foreach loop too?

I'm only able to show the username value only. I don't know how I can show the gender values in the foreach loop as well. Please don't suggest other loop types. I need to do this with a foreach loop with an array_column.

Here is my code example

```
<?php

$db_servername='localhost';
$db_username='bbb';
$db_password='1234';
$db_name='test';

$db_connect= new mysqli($db_servername,
$db_username,$db_password,
$db_name);

$db_query= "SELECT*FROM 500_users LIMIT 25";

$db_result= $db_connect->query(
$db_query);


while($db_row= $db_result->fetch_assoc()){
    $items[] = $db_row;
}

$array_structure_for_items_value_id = array_column($items,'username','gender');

foreach($array_structure_for_items_value_id as $index => $value){ 

echo $value.'<br>';//<--username
//echo $value.'<br>';<--I will like to show the gender value as well but how?

}

?>
```

Comment: The `$index` value in the loop should be your user_id

Comment: What do you mean $index?  I need to use the user_id from the data base which is different than the 1 2 3 etc the user_id has it own style of mixed letters and numbers. What your suggesting won't work for me.

Comment: You re-indexed your `$items` array using the `user_id` values from the database (that's what `array_column` with 3 parameters does). So the `$index` values in the loop will be the `user_id` values from the database.

Comment: Sorry I think your guys are not understanding what I want to do so I updated the post and change user_id to gender I'm trying to show two different array value results I hope you guys know what I mean now.

Comment: Have you tried what has been suggested?

Comment: I visited other articles on this website and I done google searches and none of them helped me out because It seems like nobody has asked this kind of question online before that i'm aware of but I think this is strange because when I add gender to my code for example $array_structure_for_items_value_id = array_column($items,'username','gender'); it show like 3 results rather than 25

Comment: I suggest you read the manual on [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), paying particular attention to example #2 (which is the way you are using it in your code) and you will see why that is. When you re-index by `gender` you can only have as many values in the output array as you have distinct `gender` values in the array. If you would just change your code back to `user_id` and **try** what has been suggested you will see that it works.

Comment: Are you able to give a code example if you don't know how then that's alright I appreciate that you took your time to try to help me out I'm just getting tired of all these dead end suggestion after suggestion with no solution and I already read that page recently and i'm still confused.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean how to show multiple array values in a foreach loop, if that is what you mean then this is my method of your example illustrating that with a third made up array value. Just to give you a better understanding of my example.

```
<?php

$db_servername='localhost';
$db_username='bbb';
$db_password='1234';
$db_name='test';

$db_connect= new mysqli($db_servername,
$db_username,$db_password,
$db_name);

$db_query= "SELECT*FROM 500_users LIMIT 25";

$db_result= $db_connect->query(
$db_query);


while($db_row= $db_result->fetch_assoc()){
    $items[] = $db_row;
}

$array_1 = array_column($items,'username');
$array_2 = array_column($items,'gender');
$array_3 = array_column($items,'password');

$iterator = new MultipleIterator();
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array_1));
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array_2));
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($array_3));

foreach($iterator as $index => $value){ 

echo $index[0].'<br>';
echo $value[0].'<br>';

echo $index[1].'<br>';
echo $value[1].'<br>';

echo $index[2].'<br>';
echo $value[2].'<br>';

}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is what I was asking for Thomas Wayne. I updated this question so people can find this more easily. This is what I was looking for and I appreciate the other users who try to help me out as well but no offense to them what I'm about to say but I knew something like this was possible and I didn't understand why you guys kept misunderstanding this question. I was asking but I blame my self for not making enough sense to make you other users know what I really wanted but thank you so much Thomas Wayne.

Answer (score 2):

In the foreach loop you've set up, $index holds the 'user_id'.

```
echo $index . ': ' . $value
```

Results in:

```
"*user_id*: *username*"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I need to use the user_id from the database not the 1 2 3 array index the user_id from the database is different it has its own style with numbers and letters combine.

Comment: I was thinking something like this foreach($array_structure_for_items_value_id as $index => $value,$value2){ but I know that won't work because that will give me an error.

Comment: When you used "array_column", you made the 'user_id' the array index. If you try the code we're suggesting you should see. Also have a look at the PHP manual for the array_column function and associative arrays.

Comment: Sorry I think your guys are not understanding what I want to do so I updated the post and change user_id to gender I'm trying to show two different array value results I hope you guys know what I mean now.

Comment: Can you please at least try the code being suggested.

Comment: I did and it was not what I wanted I realize you guys were getting confused what I was asking so I updated the post and switch out user_id with gender instead the whole point I asked this question because I wanted to find a way on how I can show the other data base value in a array and in a foreach loop as well so I did something like this $array_structure_for_items_value_id = array_column($items,'username','gender'); and it gave me a strange result it only gave me 2 usernames with no gender output aka male or female

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array like this:

```
$heroes = [
    ['id' => 10,'hero' => 'superman', 'gender' => 'm'],
    ['id' => 21,'hero' => 'wonder woman', 'gender' => 'f'],
    ['id' => 34,'hero' => 'poison ivy', 'gender' => 'f'],
    ['id' => 46,'hero' => 'penguin', 'gender' => 'm'],
];
```

And you do this:

```
$other = array_column($heroes, 'hero', 'id');
```

You get this:

```
[
    10 => 'superman',
    21 => 'wonder woman',
    34 => 'poison ivy',
    46 => 'penguin'
]
```

If you iterate through this array, you can only get the index or the hero name because that is all there is in the array.

If you do this:

```
$other = array_column($heroes, 'hero', 'gender');
```

You get this:

```
[
    'f' => 'poison ivy',
    'm' => 'penguin'
]
```

Because the gender is used as a key and keys must be unique.

Therefore, it is your use of array_column that is getting in your way.
I don't see why you just don't iterate through your array.
You do not need array_column.

```
while($db_row= $db_result->fetch_assoc()){
    $items[] = $db_row;
}

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo $item['hero'].'<br>';
    echo $item['gender'] . '<br>';
}
```